# How to query the board serial number on an Arduino nano BLE

Tags: arduino, nano

I have an Arduino nano BLE and I need to query the board serial number for improved security between connections to the board.
How can i query the serial number ?

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino Nano BLE and BLE sense uses the Nordic nRF52840 chip.
The datasheet has defined the Factory information configuration registers FICR for retrieval of the board information. There are a a couple you can use to identify the chip. e.g. Device Identifier, Device Address

The registers are memory mapped so you can read them easily.

Here is some example code:

```
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin( 9600 );
  while ( !Serial );
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print( "Device ID 0: " );
  Serial.println( NRF_FICR->DEVICEID[0], HEX );
  Serial.print( "Device ID 1: " );
  Serial.println( NRF_FICR->DEVICEID[1], HEX );

  Serial.print( "Device Address 0: " );
  Serial.println( NRF_FICR->DEVICEADDR[0], HEX );
  Serial.print( "Device Address 1: " );
  Serial.println( NRF_FICR->DEVICEADDR[1], HEX );

  delay ( 5000 );
}
```

On other arduino boards, the ArduinoUniqueID Library to gets the Manufacture Serial Number from the Atmel AVR, SAM, SAMD, STM32, and ESP Microcontroller.
The ArduinoUniqueID Library use the buildin feature to select the manufacture serial number from the microcontroler. Suported microcontroler: Atmega328pb, Atmega328p, Atmega2560, Attiny85, SAM3X8E, SAMD21, STM32, ESP8266 & ESP32.

You can find more detailed information below:

```
#include <ArduinoUniqueID.h>
```

Variable: UniqueID & UniqueIDsize
UniqueID has UniqueIDsize bytes array of the Unique Serial ID.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < UniqueIDsize; i++)
  Serial.println(UniqueID[i], HEX);
```

Method: UniqueIDdump
Print the hexadecimal bytes of the Unique Serial ID on the Stream.

```
void UniqueIDdump(Stream);
```

Variable: UniqueID8
UniqueID8 has the last 8 bytes array of the Unique Serial ID.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  Serial.println(UniqueID8[i], HEX);
```

Method: UniqueID8dump
Print the last eight hexadecimal bytes of the Unique Serial ID on the Stream.

```
void UniqueID8dump(Stream);
```

Example shows the UniqueID on the Serial Monitor.

```
#include <ArduinoUniqueID.h>

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    UniqueIDdump(Serial);
    Serial.print("UniqueID: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < UniqueIDsize; i++)
    {
        if (UniqueID[i] < 0x10)
            Serial.print("0");
        Serial.print(UniqueID[i], HEX);
        Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println();
}

void loop()
{
}
```

read more on the github project :
https://github.com/ricaun/ArduinoUniqueID